# fetch function in react-native does not work

Tags: react-native

I want to send a http request  with `fetch` function . after calling `fetch` there is no response and no error .
where is my problem ?

this is my component :(**this is for sample and I want to test http request in react-native**)

```
const App = () => {

  const changeTextHandler = async text => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result)
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }  
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={changeTextHandler}
        style={styles.textInput} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does the `onChangeText` ever get triggered? Also, you should definitely not be calling `fetch` for the `onChangeText` event as you will be triggering repeatedly every time there's a change in the `TextInput` component/field.

Comment: Does the onChangeText ever get triggered? Yes, It's your right , It's for sample ...I want only test http request

Comment: This should work just fine - perhaps the request is taking a little longer to respond. If you have the ability to check the network tab then I'd do that to see if requests are getting triggered.

Comment: @goto1 - thanks . I checked the network tab, find out Request does not trigger, Why?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The jsonplaceholder API server might be down because of some reason.